# Combining XPath and Search Queries

Tags: marklogic

**Requirement:**

Combining a `cts/search` query with a XPath query.
The XPath is a unknown user input string.

The `search:resolve` function takes "A cts:query object, a serialized cts:query, or a structured query (search:query)." ([Source](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:resolve))

**Question:**

Is there an api to convert a XPath to a cts or a structured query so I can combine the XPath and other search queries?

Not working example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := 
  <test>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </test>
return xdmp:document-insert('mike.xml', $doc);

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $xpath := '/test[name="Mike"]'
let $cts-query := cts:and-query(
   xpathToCts($xpath), (: Somehow convert XPath to cts query here :)
   cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("age"), "20")
)

return search:resolve($cts-query)
```

If there is currently no way to convert a XPath string to a `search` compatible format, is there any other way to combine XPath and cts/search queries?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1**:

I tried using the suggested `searchable-expression` option, but run into another problem combining it with `extract-document-data`:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:resolve(
  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("name"), "Mike"),
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <searchable-expression>/test[age = 20]</searchable-expression>
    <extract-document-data>
      <extract-path>/test/name</extract-path>
    </extract-document-data>
  </options>
)
```

This query does return the following extracted data:

```
<search:extracted-none>
</search:extracted-none>
```

While without the searchable expression I get the expected:

```
<search:extracted kind="element">
   <name>Mike</name>
</search:extracted>
```

If I am not mistaken the searchable-expression behaves the same as the first parameter of `cts:search`. Reading the docs it says:

> For example, if you specify //p, then p elements that match the search
>   criteria are returned.

So the resulting nodes are limited to the searchable-expression and all nodes below which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that XPath into the [`<searchable-expression>`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_60011) element in `<search:options>`, and it will essentially be AND-ed with your `cts:query`. Under the hood, all XPath expressions are converted into optimized query plans, just like `cts:queries` (with the exception that XPath expressions will always be filtered to prevent returning false positives, while filtering is optional with `cts` expressions).

But I should note that evaluating user XPath is extremely dangerous, and unchecked it is a huge hole for injection attacks. You should verify or sanitize the query to prevent this and/or ensure that the query cannot run updates, i.e: `/x/y/z[xdmp:directory-delete('/')]`. Something like this at the top of your query is a good start: `declare option xdmp:update "false";`

Comment: +1.  The best approach is to avoid XPath for queries for both of the reasons Will has cited:  XPath is too expressive to guarantee translation to efficient, unfiltered queries based on indexes and XPath is difficult to sanitize to assure security.  If hierarchical queries must be supported, it's better to use a JSON or XML representation of the hierarchy and transform into composed cts.jsonPropertyScope() or cts.elementQuery() queries.

Comment: I added an update in which I refer to your answer. Sadly I can not use searchable-expression because it changes the resulting nodes to what is given in searchable-expression. So I am further searching a way to transform a XPath query to a cts/search compatible format. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @WagnerMichael Yes, the expression selects the nodes expressed in the XPath, but you can modify your other XPath to accommodate the change, i.e. `<extract-path>/name</extract-path>` - or if the path may select nodes at varying levels, `<extract-path>/ancestor-or-self::test/name</extract-path>`. One housekeeping note - typically, changing the content of a question this much would be better served as a new question. All the changes and communication between Q&A makes it confusing for future SO users to follow.

Comment: @wst You are right, I can adjust the extract-path but I can see other limitations there. Imagine a searchable-expression like `/test/details[age=20]` (I moved age inside a element details there). Now a `element-value-query` for name does not work anymore, because the context is in `details`. A searchable-expression `/test[details/age = 20]` on the other hand would still work. So this means I would have to expect my users to "not switch search context" which would be doable as a last resort, but kind of a bummer. Hope this kind of makes sense.

Comment: @WagnerMichael I don't think you read my full comment. Changing search context can be handled by using the `ancestor-or-self::` XPath axis in your extract expression (and that constraint could also be rewritten not to change context, i.e. `/test[details/age=20]`). This works if you force Search API to query at the document/fragment level with `<search-option>unfiltered</search-option>`.

Comment: @wst I did try your `/ancestor-or-self::test/name` but it didn't work the first time I tried it. Just tried it again and now it worked. Not sure what I did wrong the first time, sorry for that. So while this solves the problem with 'extract-document-data`, I noticed `searchabe-expression` also affects searching outside of the search context.  Overall my impression is that searchable-expression is to limit a search to a specific node in a xml tree and not really suitable for joining xpath and search in nested xmls.

Comment: In my initial question the exmaple was quite non nested tho. So I still think your searchable-expression solution applies to that which is why I will accept that as an answer. Thank you very much!